# Error reading data frame dictionary TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str,

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to get a list of columns and values from a data frame column which is a nested dictionary:

Data Frame column looks like this:

```
{"id":"0","request":{"plantSearch":"true","maxResults":"51","caller":"WMS","companyCode":"GB54","purchOrg":"UPSO","Code":"5852","confidential":"false","flag":"true","service":"false","Item":"false","mastered":"true","copas":"false","pscmBlock":"false","descOperator":"CO","assocManuf":"PETK"},"response":{"hasMoreResults":"false","resultsCount":"0","execTime":"878 ms"}}
```

I am writing a code:

```
s1.columns = ['data']
l2 = []
for idx, row in s1['data'].iteritems():
    tempdf = pd.DataFrame(row['request']['plantSearch'])
    tempdf['maxResults'] = row['maxResults']
    l2.append(tempdf)


pd.concat(l2,axis = 0)
```

The issue is python is referring the 'row' as string even if it is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `json.loads` for converting to `dict` with `DataFrame` constructor for parse all data from `request` keys:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':['{"id":"0","request":{"plantSearch":"true","maxResults":"51","caller":"WMS","companyCode":"GB54","purchOrg":"UPSO","Code":"5852","confidential":"false","flag":"true","service":"false","Item":"false","mastered":"true","copas":"false","pscmBlock":"false","descOperator":"CO","assocManuf":"PETK"},"response":{"hasMoreResults":"false","resultsCount":"0","execTime":"878 ms"}}','{"id":"0","request":{"plantSearch":"true","maxResults":"51","caller":"WMS","companyCode":"GB54","purchOrg":"UPSO","Code":"5852","confidential":"false","flag":"true","service":"false","Item":"false","mastered":"true","copas":"false","pscmBlock":"false","descOperator":"CO","assocManuf":"PETK"},"response":{"hasMoreResults":"false","resultsCount":"0","execTime":"878 ms"}}']})
print (df)

                                                data
0  {"id":"0","request":{"plantSearch":"true","max...
1  {"id":"0","request":{"plantSearch":"true","max...
```

---

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame(df['data'].apply(lambda x: pd.io.json.loads(x)['request']).values.tolist())
print (df1)

   Code   Item assocManuf caller companyCode confidential  copas descOperator  \
0  5852  false       PETK    WMS        GB54        false  false           CO   
1  5852  false       PETK    WMS        GB54        false  false           CO   

   flag mastered maxResults plantSearch pscmBlock purchOrg service  
0  true     true         51        true     false     UPSO   false  
1  true     true         51        true     false     UPSO   false
```

Similar solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.io.json.loads(x)['request'] for x in df['data']])
print (df)

   Code   Item assocManuf caller companyCode confidential  copas descOperator  \
0  5852  false       PETK    WMS        GB54        false  false           CO   
1  5852  false       PETK    WMS        GB54        false  false           CO   

   flag mastered maxResults plantSearch pscmBlock purchOrg service  
0  true     true         51        true     false     UPSO   false  
1  true     true         51        true     false     UPSO   false
```

Last is possible select columns by subset:

```
cols = ['plantSearch','maxResults']
df2 = df[cols]
print (df2)
  plantSearch maxResults
0        true         51
1        true         51
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, I need the Id column as well. Could you please advise how to get that.

Comment: I think last need `df3 = df2.join(df['id'])`. I am on phone only, so untested.

Comment: I have another problem. I have hundreds of such row and one of those rows is causing the value error because data format is not correct {"key" : "123,err,1", wersd"}. Is there any way I can just skip these rows and continue with remaining?

Comment: Hard question, try create new question. But obviously it is not easy :(